# if $f$ doesn't have any underbound then $\frac1f$ is not Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve this problem:

Assume that the function $f \in \mathscr{R}$ where $\mathscr{R}$ denotes the set of all functions that are Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$.And assume that for some $c>0 , |f(x)|\geq c$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ . Prove that the reciprocal of $f, \frac1{f(x)}$, also belongs to $\mathscr R$. if $f \in \mathscr R , |f(x)|>0$ but no $c>0$ is an underbound for $|f|$, Prove that the reciprocal of $f$ is not Riemann integrable.

for proving the first part I used a theorem which says if $f \in \mathscr R$ and $m= inf \ f , \ M=sup \ f$ and the function $\varphi(t)$ is continuous on the interval $[m,M]$ then the function $h(x)=\varphi (f(x)) \in \mathscr R$.

to prove the first part  you can define $\varphi (t) = \frac1t$ and because the $\varphi$ is continuous everywhere on its domain so it is continuous on the interval $[m,0) \cup (0,M]$ (I think we don't need the point $x=0$ because $f$ is never zero). So by using the mentioned theorem we can combine two function and then $\frac1f \in \mathscr R$

for the second part this theorem doesn't work because $f$ doesn't have any underbound so we may have $m= inf \ f=0$.

I'm not sure that even my proof in the first part is correct (because the theorem says that $\varphi$ need to be continuous on the interval $[m,M]$ but my interval is different.) And also I don't know how to prove that if $f$ doesn't have any underbound then $\frac1f \notin \mathscr R$  .

Comment: *Riemann*, nor Reimann, by the way.

Comment: Hint: a Riemann integrable function over $[a,b]$ must be bounded to begin with.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I corrected it. THX

Comment: @egreg yup! I got it. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the condition “$|f(x)|>0$ for all $x$, but no $c>0$ exists so that $|f(x)|>0$ for all $x$” can be translated into

> for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x\in[a,b]$ such that $0<|f(x)|<\varepsilon$

Translate this into a condition on $1/f(x)$ and recall that a Riemann integrable function must be bounded to begin with.